# How can I emulate fingerprint on real device for tests?

Tags: adb, appium, samsung-mobile, appium-android

I can emulate finger print in Android emulator with this command:

```
adb -e emu finger touch 1
```

But how can I emulte it when I wanna add fingerprint on real device fo qa automation?